# phpmyadmin site - 403 Forbidden

Tags: http-status-code-403

I have Try to download latest phpmyadmin 6.x at this url :

https://files.phpmyadmin.net/snapshots/phpMyAdmin-6.0+snapshot-all-languages.zip

but I have this server error :

> 403 Forbidden
>
> ```
> Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch
> RequestId: tx000005bc5e0f8c953d7b5-00658f133c-2bc55ff-prg
> HostId: 2bc55ff-prg-eu-1
> ```

any fix?

Comment: We can't help with why a random web page does not work.

Comment: Blatantly off-topic:
This question has nothing to do with server, networking, or related infrastructure administration. Moreover I think that the site is protected by refrer, since I can't use it also directly from here